# Python Regular Expression nltk website extraction

Tags: python, regex, nltk

Hi I have never had to deal with regex before and I'm trying to preprocess some raw text with Python and NLTK. 
when I tried to tokenize the document using :

```
tokens = nltk.regexp_tokenize(corpus, sentence_re)
sentence_re = r'''(?x)  # set flag to allow verbose regexps
  ([A-Z])(\.[A-Z])+\.?  # abbreviations, e.g. U.S.A.
| \w+(-\w+)*            # words with optional internal hyphens
| \$?\d+(\.\d+)?%?      # currency and percentages, e.g. $12.40, 82%
| \#?\w+|\@?\w+         # hashtags and @ signs
| \.\.\.                # ellipsis
| [][.,;"'?()-_`]       # these are separate tokens
| ?:http://|www.)[^"\' ]+ # websites
'''
```

its not able to take all of the website as one single token:

```
print toks[:50]
['on', '#Seamonkey', '(', 'SM', ')', '-', 'I', 'had', 'a', 'short', 'chirp',   'exchange', 'with', '@angie1234p', 'at', 'the', '18thDec', ';', 'btw', 'SM', 'is', 'faster', 'has', 'also', 'an', 'agile', '...', '1', '/', '2', "'", '...', 'user', 'community', '-', 'http', ':', '/', '/', 'bit', '.', 'ly', '/', 'XnF5', '+', 'ICR', 'http', ':', '/', '/']
```

any help is greatly appreicated. Thanks so much!

-Florie

Comment: Natural language parsing is a heck of a place to start learning regex.

Answer (score 3):

In this tokenizer RegularExpressions are used to specify how the Tokens you want to extract from the text can look like.
I'm a bit confused which of the many regular expressions above you used, but for a very simple tokenization to non-whitespace tokens you could use:

```
>>> corpus = "this is a sentence. and another sentence. my homepage is http://test.com"
>>> nltk.regexp_tokenize(corpus, r"\S+")
['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence.', 'and', 'another', 'sentence.', 'my', 'homepage', 'is', 'http://test.com']
```

which is equivalent to:

```
>>> corpus.split()
['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence.', 'and', 'another', 'sentence.', 'my', 'homepage', 'is', 'http://test.com']
```

another approach could be using the nltk functions sent_tokenize() and nltk.word_tokenize():

```
>>> sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(corpus)
>>> sentences
['this is a sentence.', 'and another sentence.', 'my homepage is http://test.com']
>>> for sentence in sentences:
    print nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', '.']
['and', 'another', 'sentence', '.']
['my', 'homepage', 'is', 'http', ':', '//test.com']
```

though if your text contains lots of website-urls this might not be the best choice. information about the different tokenizers in the NLTK can be found [here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tokenize-module.html).

if you just want to extract URLs from the corpus you could use a regular expression like this:

```
nltk.regexp_tokenize(corpus, r'(http://|https://|www.)[^"\' ]+')
```

Hope this helps. If this was not the answer you were looking for, please try to explain a bit more precisely what you want to do and how exactely you want your tokens look like (e.g. an example input/output you would like to have) and we can help finding the right regular expression.